# Cannot implement java.util.Map

Tags: kotlin

Given this interface (literally; I can't change it):

```
interface NamedMap<K, V> : java.util.Map<K, V> {
    val name: String
}
```

How do I implement it by extending `HashMap`?

```
class NamedHashMap<K, V>(override val name: String) : NamedMap<K, V>, java.util.HashMap<K, V>()
```

This gives two compilation errors:

> Class 'NamedHashMap' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member
> **public abstract fun** size(): Int *defined in* NamedMap

> Class 'NamedHashMap' must override **public open fun** forEach(p0: BiConsumer<in K, in V>): Unit *defined in* NamedMap
> because it inherits many implementations of it

Generating `size()`:

```
override fun size(): Int {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

Leads to:

> Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (`size()I`):
>
> - public open fun <get-size>(): Int *defined in* NamedHashMap
> - public open fun size(): Int *defined in* NamedHashMap

Replacing `java.util.Map` with `Map` would fix the problem, if I could.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but what is the difference between _<get-size>(): Int_ and _size(): Int_ ? Maybe you have to override _<get-size>_ instead?

Comment: @cyberbrain I'm not too familiar either. I just wanted to see what would happen if I implemented one of the methods. I shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully explain it, but it seems Kotlin really doesn't like referencing Java collections directly. For example, this is considered a type mismatch by the Kotlin:

```kotlin
val map: java.util.Map<String, String> = java.util.HashMap<String, String>()
```

Anyway, no matter if it is possible to extend `HashMap` or not, I suggest not doing this. It is always cleaner to use aggregation and/or delegation than inheritance. In this specific case it also solves your problem, although it still requires some silly casting:

```kotlin
class NamedHashMap<K, V> private constructor(
    override val name: String,
    private val delegate: java.util.Map<K, V>
) : NamedMap<K, V>, java.util.Map<K, V> by delegate {

    constructor(name: String) : this(name, java.util.HashMap<K, V>() as java.util.Map<K, V>)
}
```

Comment: I agree with "composition over inheritance", but I didn't want to implement the 12 methods. Didn't know about the delegation syntax sugar. Seems like a good alternative, even though a bit clumsy with the needed cast.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** broot's answer is much simpler using a delegate, I would use that instead.

Your code would work if all classes involved are Kotlin collections, not Java, ie, this code compiles just fine:

```kotlin
interface NamedMap<K, V> : Map<K, V> {
    val name: String
}

class NamedHashMap<K, V>(override val name: String) : NamedMap<K, V>, HashMap<K, V>()
```

If `NamedMap` must implement `java.util.Map`, then I suggest trying this. I'm not sure if there's a better solution, but I've used this pattern many times to implement an interface based on another object.

```kotlin
interface NamedMap<K, V> : java.util.Map<K, V> {
    val name: String
}


class NamedHashMap<K, V>(override val name: String) : NamedMap<K, V> {
    private val map = HashMap<K, V>()
    override fun size() = map.size
    override fun isEmpty() = map.isNotEmpty()
    override fun containsKey(key: Any?) = map.containsKey(key)
    override fun containsValue(value: Any?) = map.containsValue(value)
    override fun get(key: Any?) = map[key]
    override fun put(key: K, value: V) = map.put(key, value)
    override fun remove(key: Any?) = map.remove(key)
    override fun putAll(m: Map<out K, V>) = map.putAll(m)
    override fun clear() = map.clear()
    override fun keySet() = map.keys
    override fun values() = map.values
    override fun entrySet() = map.entries
}
```